# Simple proof that the Catalan numbers are integers

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, catalan-numbers

As the Catalan numbers are defined as $$C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n},$$ it is not immediately clear that they are integers.

To show that they are, there's a relatively basic approach involving some binomial identities, but I wanted to avoid most of these, so I tried the following.

To show that $C_n$ is integer, it obviously suffices to show that $n + 1 \mid \binom{2n}{n}$.
Given $n$, we can see that $$ \binom{2n}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n} $$ by manipulating the fractions a little. Thus, $$ \binom{2n}{n+1} (n+1) = n \binom{2n}{n},$$ and therefore $n + 1 \mid n \binom{2n}{n}$.  Since $n$ and $n+1$ are coprime, $n+1 \mid  \binom{2n}{n}$, which should complete the proof.

Is this proof correct? For some reason, it feels like there's something off with it, although I can't see any mistakes.

Comment: It looks ok and natural to me, except that $\binom{n}{2n}$ should be $\binom{2n}{n}$

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Properties

Comment: It would have been nice if you would have shown the $2-3$ steps to derive the given idendity, but the conclusion at the end is utterly valid.

Comment: @Peter: Yeah, I will probably add them later

Comment: Your proof is great! I guess this reason it feels "off" is because you are using the fact that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is an integer, so the actual meat of the proof is contained in the proof that $\binom{n}{k}$ is an integer.

Comment: A simpler deduction from the second displayed equation is:
$$
C_n = \binom{2n}n - \binom{2n}{n + 1}.
$$
(In fact, this is the first proposition in the Wikipedia link given
by @lhf.  Still, it's worth repeating here.)